# how to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x}{x+2})^{x+1}$?

Tags: limits

I am a beginner in calculus with basic understanding of e and limit, but I cannot solve this, I need help :(

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{x+1}$$

I also wondering why I cannot use L'hospital rule here.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{x+1}}{(x+2)^{x+1}}$$
when I tried to $d/dx (x^{x+1})$, it resulted in a mess and I cannot do further calculation.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @geetha290krm If the OP states that the is starting in calculus, so why would this comment be useful for the OP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall: $$lim_ {x\to \infty} (1+n/x)^x = e^n$$
so in your case if you rewrite $\frac{x}{x+2} = 1 - \frac{2}{x+2}$
because my aim is to get your expression in a similar form to the formula I gave above, so that you can compare it with e.

$lim_ {x\to \infty} (1-\frac{2}{x+2})^{x+2}(1-\frac{2}{x+2})^{-1}$
then both factors of this limit are convergent, so we can evaluate them individually. $lim_ {x\to \infty} (1-\frac{2}{x+2})^{x+2} = e^{-2}$ (you could substitute x+2 for say y, if you want to see why it corresponds to the equation for e) and $lim_ {x\to \infty} (1-\frac{2}{x+2})^{-1} = 1$
so your limit is $e^{-2}*1=e^{-2}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's rule is valid here - that is, since the numerator and denominator both approach $+\infty$, $\lim \frac{f}{g} = \lim \frac{f'}{g'}$ is true. But as you noticed, that step makes this formula more complicated, not less. And no matter how many times you apply it, you'll still have a "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" form. So it doesn't help directly.

One method that often works nicely for limits of composite functions in a form "$1^\infty$" or "$\infty^0$" is to take the logarithm, and then apply L'Hospital's rule. We can do this because the function $\ln$ is continuous, so the limit of the logarithm is the logarithm of the limit. This problem is in a "$1^\infty$" form, so let's try it.

$$ \begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{x+1} \\
\ln L &= \ln \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{x+1} \\
 \ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{x+1} \\
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} (x+1) \ln\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right) \\
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)}{\frac{1}{x+1}} 
\end{align*} $$

Here's the point to check that L'Hospital's rule actually applies. (The "$1^\infty$" or "$\infty^0$" form is just a hint that it will likely help.) It does, since the numerator approaches $\ln 1 = 0$ and the denominator also approaches $0$.

One more step with a logarithm rule before taking the derivatives makes it a little easier:

$$ \begin{align*}
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x - \ln(x+2)}{\frac{1}{x+1}} \\
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+2}}{-\frac{1}{(x+1)}^2} \\
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-2(x+1)^2}{x(x+2)} \\
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}{1+\frac{2}{x}} \\
\ln L &= -2 \\
L &= e^{-2}
\end{align*} $$

At the end, taking $\exp$ of both sides reverses the first step of applying $\ln$. (Writing $\ln L = $ with each step or line keeps it clear what's going on, and helps us not forget that last step.)